# what are the payment gateways are possible in civicrm for NGO in India

Tags: wordpress, extension, import, payment-processor, search

Any suggestion about the payment gateways are possible in civicrm for NGO in India

Comment: I have no knowledge or experience of any sort about international payment gateways, but Stripe seems to be available and is civi compatible. PayPal perhaps as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use paypal, we have done integration with Icici for one-off payment and enach for recurring